# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: (again)

Tags: java

I've read through a number of similar threads, but in my nOObishness can't seem to figure out how I can apply the answers to my code. Sorry...

When running the code below I'm getting the error:
*java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:*

The outcome of the program is okay. I'm getting all the capitals from the string that I have entered with the scanner. But the error message is kinda in the way.

Any help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a senctence with capitals: ");
        String inputString = in3.nextLine();

        int stringLength = String.valueOf(inputString).length();
        int i = 0;

        while (i <= stringLength)
        {
            int subsStart = i;
            int subsEind = i + 1;

            String stringToCheck = inputString.substring(subsStart, subsEind);

            char letterToCheck = stringToCheck.charAt(0);

            if (Character.isUpperCase(letterToCheck)) 
            {
                System.out.println(letterToCheck);
            }
            i++;

        }
        in3.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when i == stringLength? How does substring work?

Comment: And what happens if `i == stringLength - 1`?

Comment: And why do you need to `String.valueOf` something that's already a string?

Comment: You should also have a look at [for loop](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=for+loop+java&oq=for+loop+java&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2624j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Its more suitable than `while` in your case.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback guys. Just getting started in Java and I appreciate you're comments and will check them all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of places where you are indexing off the end of the string. First, your main loop should not go through `stringLength` because the length of the string is an illegal index into the string. At most, the loop should go through `stringLength - 1`, which means the loop should be written

```
while (i < stringLength) // NOT i <= stringLength
```

But there's another problem. Inside the loop, you are computing

```
String stringToCheck = inputString.substring(subsStart, subsEind);
```

and then later evaluate

```
char letterToCheck = stringToCheck.charAt(0);
```

which makes the assumption that `stringToCheck` is not the empty string. Unfortunately, that assumption fails when `subsStart == stringLength`. Therefore you need to stop your outer loop *before* `stringLength`:

```
while (i < stringLength - 1)
```

However, since you're only interested in one letter at a time, I wouldn't bother with extracting the substring. Also, you have a lot of redundant variables in your code. I would write it something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence with capitals: ");
    String inputString = in3.nextLine();

    int stringLength = inputString.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        char letterToCheck = inputString.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isUpperCase(letterToCheck)) 
        {
            System.out.println(letterToCheck);
        }

    }
    // in3.close(); // not really needed for System.in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i <= stringLength)
```

should be

```
while (i < stringLength)
```

For eaxample, `hello` has string length of 5, but in terms of indexing, it is only up to 4.. 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: Actually, `while (i < stringLength - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Last two iterations will fail.

```
String stringToCheck = inputString.substring(subsStart, subsEind);
```

Tries to read indexes `stringLength` & `stringLength+1` but there are only `stringLength-1`.